# How does QAbstractItemView select which delegate to use

Tags: c++, qt

Qt's "Star delegate" and "SpinBox delegate" examples just use QTableView::setItemDelegate() methods and each delegate checks whether it can process data using QVariant::canConvert().
In my case I have a few types of data, for example: strings, ints, and vectors of chars. I need to display strings and ints as usual and display vectors in different ways, depending on what type of data it represents. For example, some vectors firstly should be converted to integer and displayed in combobox where each integer is converted to appropriate word (1 - "Opened", 2 - "Closed", etc.); other vectors should be converted to integers and displayed in comboboxes; finally, some vectors should be displayed as is.

Each of above-mentioned vectors represents data of my object in tree-like structure. I have a list which says that properties 1-3 are of type 1, properties 4-5 are of type 2 and so on. I intend to map model's number of column to number of property; lately I should also be able to manipulate views enabling/disabling columns or swaping their places.

And the question is how to organize delegates to show my data properly.

OOPS: I found setItemDelegateForColumn() method and it seems it is what I need. But still, if someone has what to say, I would be grateful.

Comment: You may store additional data to custom user roles. For example: `model->setData( index, QVector<int>{}, Qt::UserRole+1 );` And in delegate: `if ( index->data( Qt::UserRole+1 ).isValid() { /*TODO*/ }`;